# How do I get rid of sliver that appears between adjacent elements in Safari on iPad?

Tags: ios, colors, css-position

I have two absolutely positioned adjacent elements that share the same background color. They appear to be one single element on my desktop and laptop, but there's a plainly visible "border" of sorts - a sliver of translucent color - between the two elements when viewed on the iPad.

If I had to guess I'd say it's due to the different method by which vector objects are drawn in the browser in iOS, but that's just a guess based on some vague information I heard in a talk once.

Here's an entire sample page that can show the issue if you can run it on an iPad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                position: relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            #left {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 50px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #right {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 50px;
                width: 150px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs if Safari is scaling the page.

Safari scales elements individually, often resulting in each element having a 1-pixel-wide translucent edge on one or more sides. Then when the scaled elements are placed side by side, the overlapping translucent edges are still not 100% opaque, so some of the background leaks through.

The problem isn't limited to absolutely-positioned elements; it applies to all adjacent elements (except images, it seems).

For instance, if a table is styled with `td { background-color:black }` there will sometimes be subpixel slivers of background showing between the table cells. Even two adjacent spans exhibit the problem.

My solution is to restructure the page so that adjacent elements of the same color are wrapped in a container, and the background is applied to the container. This is a lot of work. In your case, a quick fix would be to overlap the divs by 1 pixel.

I do consider this to be an iPad bug. None of my Windows browsers (including Safari) have this problem when zooming a page.